# MySql Import via TOAD Prompts for Variables During Insert

Tags: mysql, toad

I dump data like this in order to keep my procedures and image data...

```
mysqldump --hex-blob --routines -u XXXX -p XXXX > dump.sql
```

I then drag dump.sql into Toad for MySql v7.0.0.2038, I press F5 (Execute SQL) and it chugs along for a while then a popup appears asking me to enter a value for a bind variable.  I'm new to MySql, in Oracle I would run `SET DEFINE OFF` and it would treat the character as simply a character which is what I want.  I cannot find the equivalent in MySql.

I found the character causing this, its a question mark, a bind variable.  I just want it to go in the table as a question mark.  TOAD has a little info but still doesn't say how to suppress this: http://dev.toadformysql.com/webhelp/Content/Editor/Set_Bind_Variables.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.  I will just load the dump file via the command line like this...

```
mysql> source C:/temp/dump.sql
```

I did verify that doing it this way the question marks are inserted as question marks.

Still would be nice to figure out if there is a way to suppress that bind variable prompt in TOAD tho.